# Image recognition/classification using Microsoft ML.net 0.2 (Machine learning)

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

I want to do Image recognition/classification using the newly release Microsoft ML.net 0.2 ....is there a code sample available. Does it supports analyzing images & creating models out of it ?

Answer (score 5):

With ML.NET still being in an early preview, doing anything with unstructured data (images, text, video) is still unavailable. If you look at the [roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/ROADMAP.md#featurization-improvements), though, it is planned to include text and image features. As of now, you can only use it for structured, tabular data such as CSVs.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply..... Can i Use microsoft Cognitive service/CNTK to achieve image recognition/classification ?

Comment: The [Custom Vision service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/) is perfect for classification. :)

Answer (score 3):

Accord.net is an alternative to Microsoft.ML that has image classification
You can download it from 
http://accord-framework.net 
By the accord.net many algorithms like classification , regression and clustering could be done

Answer (score 1):

ML.NET, version 0.6.0 supports Image classification/scoring from pretrained TF models. 
Take a look at the C# sample found at [DeepLearning_ImageClassification_TensorFlow](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_ImageClassification_TensorFlow)