# Image analysis in C# with ML.Net

Tags: c#, tensorflow, machine-learning, ml.net

I have thousands of jpegs in a folder structure. These images are a snapshot of my driveway in 2560 x 1440 and are taken and stored every 60 seconds.

I'd like to create a program that can detect, from analyzing an image, whether I or my wife, was home at that particular time or not. I have a red car, she has a bright yellow car. So a simple color threshold should probably suffice. Another clear distinction is that we both have our own spot and never park in the others. Also, other people don't use the driveway (and if they do, I don't mind a false positive). One minor complication is that the camera's switch to black/white during the dark (but that may be when the parking spot rather than the color might come in handy).

So I was hoping I could use [ML.Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet) and train a model with some hand-annotated images where I tag the image with data whether I see my or her car in the driveway. I was thinking of annotating maybe a 100 to a couple of hundred images for day and another set for night and feed all these images to ML.Net to train it and then have analyse a few 100 images where I can manually check the results and correct any mistakes and then create a sort of feedback-loop to train on a few hundred more images.

Once the training is complete I'd like to analyze all images currently stored and each new image as it comes in to generate some data on when I'm (or my wife is) home, away etc.

My problem is (and this is probably going to be the reason for the question being closed as "too broad" or something): I have no clue on how to do this. I have seen [awesome tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/playlists) that all make it seem like child's play but when I then try to do this in C# (my language of choice) and look for [ML.Net Howto's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/) I can't seem to find anything that helps me in the right direction.

For example: [Train a machine learning model with data that's not in a text file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-non-file-training-data-ml-net). I'm a competent programmer so it's peanuts to create CSV file / database / whatever that has `1.jpg -> rob home, wife not home` data. But the "How To" doesn't explain how to feed the image into ML.Net and I haven't been able to find anything that does. Most probable cause is that I'm new to ML(.Net) and probably that I'm too stubborn to give up trying to accomplish this in C# but the information available is, weird as it sounds, overwhelming but also scarce. The information available usually leads me going down some rabbit hole only to find out after way too long that it's not what I want *or* I can't find anything that hints of me going in the right direction.

So long story short; **tl;dr**:

How do I feed images into ML.Net, how do I tell ML.Net that my/her car is in the driveway for any given image (training) and how do I get ML.Net to *tell me* whether it thinks I'm / my wife is home or not for a given image? Or is this [not possible](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/ROADMAP.md#featurization-improvements) (currently)? **I'm NOT looking for complete code** but for pointers, hints, links, tutorials, examples or whatever may help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you might find something usefull here [Image recognition/classification using Microsoft ML.net 0.2 (Machine learning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929258/image-recognition-classification-using-microsoft-ml-net-0-2-machine-learning)

However I would encourage you to consider python as weapon of choice for your task.
Here you would just store the data in different folders according to the label, you @home, your wife @home, both @home, no car in the drive way, other 
and you are ready to go.
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

It probably won't take you more than a weekend, and thats inlcuding to learn the bacics of python.

Edit: 
I seems as it still does not support to train image classification tasks using ML.Net: "Again, note that this sample only uses/consumes a pre-trained TensorFlow model with ML.NET API. Therefore, it does not train any ML.NET model. Currently, TensorFlow is only supported in ML.NET for scoring/predicting with existing TensorFlow trained models."

There is a thread about it here https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5379,

What you could try is uses: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page in combination with OpenCV, this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-python-program-vehicle-detection-video-frame/ is an example in python but it should translate well to c++ or c# using emgu. Once the car is detected check for the position and color. This approach would probably also avoid labeling any data.

Alternatively use a pre trained model h5 file and load into ML.Net then check for the position and mean color to check whos car it is.

Comment: The question you link to has a few issues: first, it's about 0.2, which, if I understand correctly, is a 'prehistoric' version. ML.Net is on 0.8 and *apparently* a lot has changed since then (since most 0.2 code doesn't work). Then the 1st answer says it's not possible, the 2nd suggests Accord.net which was not my question and the [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53121530/215042) links to a 404 but says it's possible.

I know the basics of Python (and a whole slew of other languages) but, again, that's not my goal. I want to achieve this in C#.

Comment: I do, however, look at examples / tutorials for other languages as it may give me keywords or techniques or whatever that I can then Google C# (or (ML).Net) specific information for. But your answer and taking the time to type it is appreciated, even though I found the linked question myself - I should've mentioned that in my question maybe. But thanks anyway! What is described in the blogpost you link is about what I'm trying to do but then in C# / ML.Net. So I do have some new keywords I can try.

Comment: This might be more helpful https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_ImageClassification_TensorFlow

And should show how you can use ML.Net for Image Classfication Tasks, I suggest to use transfer learning to avoid annotating too many images manually.

Comment: One more sample: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_TensorFlowEstimator